# Como fazer para validar o campo ao passar um valor pelo método 'change'

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, html-select

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou novato em javascript, gostaria de ajuda com um problema.

Consegui fazer com que ao selecionar o valor do primeiro select de "UNIDADE" o select de baixo viesse com o mesmo valor, porém como podem ver na imagem ele fica como required ainda e não habilita o campo para finalizar a compra. Como posso resolver esse problema?

Obs.: segue o código JS/TS utilizado:

```
class UnitSelection {
get targets(): NodeListOf<HTMLSelectElement> {
    return document.querySelectorAll('[data-option-id]');
}

init(): void {
    this.attachListeners();
}

attachListeners(): void {
    this.targets.forEach(option => {
        option.addEventListener('change', (e: Event) =>
            this.handleChange(e)
        );
    });
}

handleChange(e: Event): void {
    const target: EventTarget | null | HTMLSelectElement = e.currentTarget;
    if (!(target instanceof HTMLSelectElement)) {
        return;
    }

    const value = target.value;

    this.targets.forEach(target => {
        if (target.value == '') {
            target.value = value;
        }
    });
}} const unitSelection = new UnitSelection(); unitSelection.init();
```

HTML:

```
<select name="place" location-select data-item-id="<?php echo $_item->getId(); ?>" data-product-id="<?php echo $_item->getProductId(); ?>" data-option-id="<?php echo $optionId; ?>">
                <?php if ($placeList) : ?>
                    <?php if (is_string($placeList)) : ?>
                        <option value="1"><?php echo $placeList ?></option>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                        <?php foreach ($placeList as $key => $place) : ?>
                            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($place) ?>

                            <?php if ($_formatedOptionValue['value'] === $selectedOption) : ?>
                                <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php else : ?>
                    <option value="1">Unidade Padrão</option>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </select>
```

Agradeço a ajuda ;)

Comment: Se estiver usando jQuery, use o método [.one](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Pela explicação da pergunta, vc não quer dar um change em todos os selects, quer dar em apenas um e alterar o valor dos outros.

Comment: @Sam isso, quero que ao selecionar uma unidade no select de cima todos os outros tambem sejam alterados para o mesmo valor.

Comment: Só no de cima? Está usando jQuery?

Comment: @Sam não, estou iniciando nos estudos ainda

Answer (score -1):

Pode se fazer da seguinte forma para alterar os selects que estão acima do que você esta alterando

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll(".unity");

function selectChange(end=0,value) {
  for(let i = 0; i< end; i++){
    selects[i].value = value
  }
}

function setOnChangeEvent() {
  for(let i = 0; i< selects.length; i++){
    selects[i].onchange = () => {
      selectChange(i,selects[i].value);
    }
  }
}

setOnChangeEvent();
```

```html
<label>Unidade:</label><br/>
<select class="unity">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
<select class="unity">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
<select class="unity">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
<select class="unity">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Entendi seu ponto mas, por exemplo, quando ele selecionar o primeiro nenhum select muda junto, so quando ele modificar o último.  Fazendo do jeito que voce falou resolveria o problema de ao selecionar uma unidade no primeiro select o restante, com ele incluso, permanecerem como obrigatorios?